# Manually update kernel `saved_entry` to the latest installed kernel after removing kernel (grub2-mkconfig didn't help)

Tags: fedora, kernel, grub2

I removed kernel version 6.4.4 and 6.4.6 using

```bash
Version="6.4.4-200.fc38"
sudo dnf remove kernel-{core,devel}-"${Version}"

Version="6.4.6-200.fc38"
sudo dnf remove kernel-{core,devel}-"${Version}"
```

- After removing we can see that `saved_entry` is not updated even after running: `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "/boot/grub2/grub2-efi.cfg"`

```bash
$ sudo grub2-editenv list
saved_entry=6ed4118b39784b2d90abcfc4a6041cfe-6.4.6-200.fc38.x86_64
menu_auto_hide=1
boot_success=1
boot_indeterminate=1

$ sudo dnf list --installed | grep -E ^kernel
kernel.x86_64                                        6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel.x86_64                                        6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-core.x86_64                                   6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-core.x86_64                                   6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-devel.x86_64                                  6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-devel.x86_64                                  6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-headers.x86_64                                6.4.4-200.fc38                      @updates               
kernel-modules.x86_64                                6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-modules.x86_64                                6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-modules-core.x86_64                           6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-modules-core.x86_64                           6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64                          6.3.11-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64                          6.3.12-200.fc38                     @updates               
kernel-srpm-macros.noarch                            1.0-19.fc38                         @updates
```

## Any suggestion?